# Ionic framework: Structuring providers and api urls

Tags: angularjs, api, url, ionic-framework

I starting a new ionic project and i want to separate providers and components in order to organise  my project structure, I want to create a separate file contain the urls of my api.

how to decalre urls in a urls.ts file ?

here is the project structure :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use anyone in following 
1. Enum
2. Const variables

example

```html
export enum URLS {
  ADD_USER = "http://example.com/user/add",
  DELETE_USER = "http://example.com/user/delete"
  }
```

and you can use like **URLS.ADD_USER**

2. Const Variables

```html
export const ADD_USER = "http://example.com/user/add"
```

Like that and you can directly use that by importing.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class and constant key value pair array of your urls then export the class, then you can access the all urls of your application by using the above created class and from the constant key value array. Thanks. Hope this was you looking for!